# How to override the toString() method on JS objects to use JSON.stringify()?

Tags: scala.js

I'm tired of writing `blah: "${JSON.stringify(target)}"` when I deal with my DTO objects, I just want to write `blah: "$target"`.

My DTOs look like:

```
@js.native
trait AuthConnectionDetails extends js.Object {
  def clientId: String = js.native
  def accountHostname: String = js.native
}
```

These DTOs are used to parse the content of some REST API calls, like:

```
val response = js.JSON.parse(xmlHttpRequest.responseText).
  asInstanceOf[AuthConnectionDetails]
```

I don't mind changing how I define my DTO objects to do this (maybe I should be using case classes for my DTOs or something, instead of native js traits?), but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried writing a trait that I could mixin, but that didn't work and I tried writing an implicit extension method but that didn't work either.

My implicit code that didn't seem to work for toString:

```
object JsonToString {
  implicit class JsObjectExtensions(val target: js.Object) extends AnyVal {
    override def toString:String = JSON.stringify(target)
    def json:String = JSON.stringify(target)
  }
}
```

So I can do `blah: "${target.json}"`, which is better - but I'd especially like to get rid of those braces.

Is there any way to do this with scala.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. That's because string interpolation will always use the `toString()` method *of the object itself*, no matter what is *declared* in its types or in implicit classes (this is a Scala thing in general).

The only way you could achieve this would be to actually modify the objects by patching them up with a custom `toString()` method every time you create one. That would include when you parse them from a JSON string. I'm pretty sure that would be worse than calling `.json` when you stringify them.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to, you could write your custom string interpolator:

```
implicit class JsonHelper(private val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def dejson(args: Any*): JSONObject = {
    sc.checkLengths(args)
    s(args.map(jsonify))
  }

  private def jsonify(arg: Any) = arg match {
    case obj: js.Object => JSON.stringify(obj)
    case _ => arg.toString
  }
}
```

You can now use this like this:

```
dejson"hello: $target, world: $target2"
```